# Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): / Killed

Tags: python, linux, amazon-ec2, conda, ubuntu-18.04

I have a fresh EC2 Ubuntu 18.04
I have installed anaconda as it it in the official guide
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/

```
apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx libegl1-mesa libxrandr2 
libxrandr2 libxss1 libxcursor1 libxcomposite1 libasound2 libxi6 
libxtst6 64 bit installation
```

But then I have YML files that I have used to create conda environments before on other EC2s and when I ma tiring to setup a new environment with it

`ubuntu@ip........:~$ conda env create --name my_env_name --file=my_env_file.yml`

it it gives me the following error

`Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): / Killed`

Now I am trying with the following guide

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Adding more RAM helps I switched from 0.5 GB to 8GB RAM than the problem disappears

Answer (score 21):

Assigning more RAM, as suggested in the accepted answer by @sogu, will probably cost you money.

You can alternatively solve this problem free-of-charge by assigning swap space instead. [This blog post](https://paulshipley.id.au/blog/coding-tips/add-swap-space-to-amazon-lightsail/) provides a simple few commands to allocate 1G of swap space, which was enough for conda to install most packages in my case:

```sh
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile 
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile 
sudo mkswap /swapfile 
sudo swapon /swapfile 
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak 
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

Comment: I do not understand why this answer was not accepted as the official one, because it works.

Comment: this should be the correct answer

Comment: This worked for me with a 5-buck DO droplet.

Comment: this works on wsl

Comment: works great, could you add code, how to destroy swapfile after no longer needed