# Conda install Mamba Error: Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): / Killed

Tags: bioinformatics, environment, mamba

I am trying to install mamba through conda on my linux terminal on my chormebook. Please help. I need to install this for a final exmam. My professor just tells me look online. I am not a programmer and I am new to bioinformatics so please provide explanantions with suggestions.

I keep getting an error message. I have tried reassigning space according to another thread and it did not work:
[Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): / Killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821441/collecting-package-metadata-repodata-json-killed)

```
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile 
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile 
sudo mkswap /swapfile 
sudo swapon /swapfile 
sudo cp /etc/fstab /etc/fstab.bak 
echo '/swapfile none swap sw 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

The output was after '''sudo swapon /swapfile''' was 'swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Function not implemented'

I tried '''curl -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' [https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json'''](https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json%27%27%27)

I got a bunch of script then tried '''conda create -n py34d20 python=3.4 pip=9 django -c conda-forge''' per this thread: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/9728

I get the same results which are:
'Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): - Killed '

The instructions my professor gave to download to show what I should get.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JAE4.png)

The point is to install clustal environment using mamba to align genes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF5Fk.png)