# The conda code conda create env -f xxx.yaml is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to create a new environment in conda (in linux) with a yaml file just like the code from the docs

```
create env create -f env.yaml
```

but keeps giving this:

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: - Killed
```

I saw that others people with that same problem was responded that it was a problem with space but I have almost 100GB of space. I also am in a env that's has conda 23.1.0 installed and the yaml file is wrote correct since others people could used normally.

**UPDATEE:**
I then tried to install my own windows 10 and this error appeared:

```
  (base) PS C:\Users\Rosa\Downloads\RASflow-master\RASflow-master> conda env create -f env.yaml  Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done Solving environment: failed
    
    ResolvePackageNotFound:
      - hisat2=2.1.0
      - multiqc=1.5
      - salmon=0.14.1
      - graphviz=2.40.1
      - trim-galore=0.6.2
      - samtools=1.9
      - bioconductor-edger=3.26.0
      - htseq=0.11.2
      - subread=1.6.4
      - bioconductor-deseq2=1.22.1
```

When I tried to install these packages with the codes available in anaconda it didn't work either and I got this:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\Rosa\Downloads\RASflow-master\RASflow-master>
(base) PS C:\Users\Rosa\Downloads\RASflow-master\RASflow-master> conda install -c bioconda hisat2 
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - hisat2

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/free/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/free/noarch
```

This is the the env.yaml file:

```
name: rasflow 
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - bioconda
  - r
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - snakemake=5.3.0
  - graphviz=2.40.1
# command tool installs
  - R=3.5.1
  - python=3.6.7
# r channel installs
  - r-yaml=2.2.0
  - r-statmod=1.4.30
  - r-gplots=3.0.1
# conda-forge channel installs
  - r-heatmap.plus=1.3
  - r-readr=1.3.1
  - r-hash=3.0.1
# bioconda channel installs
  - fastqc=0.11.8
  - trim-galore=0.6.2
  - multiqc=1.5
  - salmon=0.14.1
  - hisat2=2.1.0
  - samtools=1.9
  - subread=1.6.4  # featureCounts included
  - htseq=0.11.2  # htseq-count included
  - bioconductor-edger=3.26.0
  - bioconductor-deseq2=1.22.1
  - qualimap=2.2.2a
  - bioconductor-mygene=1.18.0
  - bioconductor-tximport=1.12.1
  - bioconductor-enhancedvolcano=1.2.0
  - bioconductor-biomart=2.38.0
```

What can be wrong?? Any help would be good!Thanks in advance!

What can be the problem? All the help will be great

Thank you

Comment: The "Killed" message usually indicates a lack of RAM memory, not storage.

Comment: aaah thankyouu! Actually now I trying using the code without the env like some others said and I found the real problem:PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - env.yaml. DO you know how I change that?? I install the lasted version of miniconda

Comment: That error message  indicates that the packages listed in the `env.yaml` file are not available in the default conda channels. Try:
`conda config --add channels channel_name`
Replace `channel_name` with the name of the channel that contains the missing packages.

Comment: Bioconda doesn't support Windows. I suggest using WSL2 and installing a Linux version of Mambaforge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to add the channels with the:

```
conda config --add channels <channel_name>
```

And then

```
conda env update -f env.yaml
```

But the main problem is still the fact that there is not enough memory.
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#collecting-package-metadata-repodata-json-killed

Comment: This arg was not found, even if a but the env first. The error that I said in the last comment is was:
`PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - env.yaml
Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page`

Comment: +The `--no build ` Sorry the code look bad. Maybe the problem its the version I installed??

Comment: Maybe this helps you with the memory problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64821441/collecting-package-metadata-repodata-json-killed/67454782#67454782